# How can I specialize a template class member function?

Tags: c++, templates, traits, template-specialization, specialization

Consider the following sample:

```
    template <class T, class U>
class Test {
public:
    void f(){std::cout<<"f() not specized"<<std::endl;}
    void g(){std::cout<<"g() not specized"<<std::endl;}
    void h(){std::cout<<"h() not specized"<<std::endl;}

    //void g<long, double>(){}
};
```

Here I have en error on the commented code.
I guess the only way achieve expected result is to spacialize the whole class. But in the class mentioned below, I cannot use the default behaviour of my original class (e. f() and h() functions).

```
template <>
class Test<long, double> {
public:
    void f(){std::cout<<"f() specized long, double"<<std::endl;}
};
```

So is there a way to spacialize the function in the original class??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, you can [do it with a definition](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/130335f6748c6a98):

```
template<>
void Test<long, double>::f(){std::cout<<"f() specialized long, double"<<std::endl;}
```

Comment: Thanks.
It worked. But I wander how does it work, because the body of f<long, double> is never declared in the class' namespace??

Comment: @EduardRostomyan, A definition is also a declaration. Even though that doesn't work for declaring members of a class, it does work for declaring members of a fully specialized class template. I'm not sure I could do a technical explanation justice. However, you can find some explanation and examples [in a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).